# How to get CatalogRule Detail at Cart page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show catalog rule details like(Rule name and Description) at Cart page.

But i don't get any methods for that.

I also tried `getAppliedRuleIds()` method over product object. But not getting any things in result. I think this methods used for Shopping cart rule.

If you know any methods for catalog rule. Please answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code get these details. I am assuming the rule id is 1 which you want to get

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1);
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->name;
echo $rule->description;
```

for catalog rule try below code

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1);
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->name;
echo $rule->description;
```

Comment: Thanks for your try. But it is not actual solution. I just want to get applied rule details which is applied on product at cart page.

Comment: You need to get the Id of that rule and than use the above code

Comment: yes i know. Please see my question i mentioned that i am not able to fetch rule id ( using getAppliedRuleIds). so how to get rule id first.

Comment: sorry not able to fetch rule id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the applied rules of product using below method. Add this method in 
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php.

You can get the applied rule id of a product by passing the product object.

```
$ruleid = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getProductPriceRuleId(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId()));
```

Once you get the ruleid you can retrieve the title and description using ram sharma code.

```
 $rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleid);
 $rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
 echo $rule->name;
 echo $rule->description;
```

Rule.php

```
public function getProductPriceRuleId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    $priceRules = null;
    $productId  = $product->getId();
    $storeId    = $product->getStoreId();
    $websiteId  = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
    if ($product->hasCustomerGroupId()) {
        $customerGroupId = $product->getCustomerGroupId();
    } else {
        $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    }
    $rulesData = $this->_getResource()->getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);

    $dateTs     = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($storeId);
    $cacheKey   = date('Y-m-d', $dateTs) . "|$websiteId|$customerGroupId|$productId|ruleid";
    $rule_id = '';
    if (!array_key_exists($cacheKey, self::$_priceRulesData)) {

        $rulesData = $this->_getResource()->getRulesFromProduct($dateTs, $websiteId, $customerGroupId, $productId);
        if ($rulesData) {
            foreach ($rulesData as $ruleData) {
                if ($product->getParentId()) {
                    $rule_id = $ruleData['rule_id'];
                    if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    $rule_id = $ruleData['rule_id'];
                    if ($ruleData['action_stop']) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = $rule_id;
        } else {
            self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey] = null;
        }
    } else {
        return self::$_priceRulesData[$cacheKey];
    }
    return null;
}
```